# How to generate order number in this format ORD000001 in hibernate and spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How to generate order number in this format ORD000001 in hibernate and spring

Please help me to generate above number.i tried various ways to generate this sequence number but no solution worked well.

Comment: I think it would be easier to handle it inside your database with a sequence

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;
import org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.UUID;

public class RandomIdentifierGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

  private final static String label = "ORD";
  private final static SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();

  public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor sessionImplementor, Object o) throws HibernateException {
    long val = sr.nextLong();
    return label + Long.toString(Math.abs(val), Character.MAX_RADIX);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanx but how to impliment  in hibernate annotation?

Comment: Make this class as a component and autowire it in the DAO.

Comment: thanx .OK it work fine .one more thing i want to generate trip order  like this TRP001(SYSTEM DATE)001.eg TRP001 2016-05-16 001.is there any simplest way to generate this format

Comment: I got IlligalArgumentException : Can't format given object as a number  when i use   – Anthony Raymond code

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really need is parse in some more functional way the orders generated, then i wont go for the approach of generate a randomID i would use the real ID of your order, which will be sequential and format it to give the result as you wish. In code would be something like this:

```
Class Order

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Transient
public String getOrderIdBusiness(){
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("ORD000000");
    return myFormatter.format(id);
}
```

Comment: I would go for this too

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond great I think is a easy solution and readable :)

Comment: I want to send message from web portal but my api  can not sending  String with space .How i can print string without space

Comment: Could you detail a little bit more your problem or make a new question? i dont understand what you mean, the space is in the middle of your string? you can use regexp to remove it